# how twelve point star works correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am new to front-end developer and I am learning css basics , I can understand the following code

```css
#twelve-point-star {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

#twelve-point-star:before {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* Rotate */
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#twelve-point-star:after {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* Rotate */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<p>twelve point star</p>
<div id="twelve-point-star"></div>
```

We have created a different kind of triangle  and rotate that position to achieve this position. But what purpose we used `:before` and `:after` ?

Comment: It's 3 aquares - `before` and `after` are 30deg rotated in different directions. You can see it by using devtools in your browser. Without `before` and `after` it would be just a simple blue square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See...you need total 12 stars. If you apply css only `#twelve-point-star`, you will get 4 corners...you need 8 corners more...For that you have used the `:before` to get 4 corners more and `:after` to get final 4 corners pseudo classes to get total 12 corners..

Try to change the color you will see the real visual.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#twelve-point-star {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   margin:30px;
   background: blue;
   position: absolute;
}
#twelve-point-star:before {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: red;
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   /* Rotate */
   -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
   transform: rotate(30deg);
}
#twelve-point-star:after {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: black;
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   /* Rotate */
   -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
   transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>
twelve point star
</p>
<div id="twelve-point-star">
</div>

</body>
```

Reference Link

- [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)
- [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: can I get this shape with out  using ::before and after  ?

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi you can use `svg` to make that kind of shape..but for that you have to learn `svg`...As a new to html/css you are good with your solution....For reference to `svg`  https://codepen.io/cwmanning/pen/Hugye

Answer (score 1):

```
:before
```

means that before every #twelve-point-star, the css in #twelve-point-star:before will be applied to #twelve-point-star. Likewise for :after, except that it is place after every #twelve-point-star. So what happens in the code is that you basically make 3 squares that are rotated in different directions, which creates that effect.

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) is a great source for you to learn css.

Comment: hi can i achieve this shape with out using ::before and ::after snippet?

Comment: If you wanted,  you can have 3 divs with different ids.  <div id="x"></div><div id="y"></div><div id="z"></div> and then replace the :before and :after with #y and #z.  That would produce the same result.